# Refactor PHP Array Grouping and Mapping

Tags: php, arrays, multidimensional-array, refactoring, stdclass

**Goal**

I'm wondering if there is a better way to code this problem? I'd like to refactor if possible.

**Requirements:**

- Given a list of ACRISS Vehicle Codes (http://www.acriss.org/car-codes.asp), group the vehicles into categories based on their characters. A car may be grouped into 1 or more categories. LTAR Example: Since L is the first character it would be grouped into Luxury and since T is the second character it would also be grouped as a Convertible.
- **Compact** - CB..,CC.., CD.. (any vehicle codes that begin with CB, CC, or CD. Examples: CBAR, CDAR, CCAR)
- **Economy** - EB..,EC..,ED..
- **Full-Size** - FB..,FC..,FD..
- **Luxury** - L... (starts with L)
- **Van** - .F.. (second character is F)
- **Convertible** - .T.. (second character is T, example: DTAR)
- **Hybrid** - ...H (fourth character is H or I, example: CCAH)
- **Electric** - ...C (fourth character is C or E, example: CCAE)

**Input Examples (each vehicle code will always have 4 characters):**

1. ECAR
2. CCAR
3. SFAR
4. STAR
5. LTAR

Expected Output:

1. [category] => Array ([0] => Economy)
2. [category] => Array ([0] => Compact)
3. [category] => Array ([0] => SUV)
4. [category] => Array ([0] => Convertible)
5. [category] => Array ([0] => Luxury [1] => Convertible)

**Code:**

```
        $vehicle_code = str_split($new_car->type);
        $categories = [
            'CB' => 'Compact',
            'CC' => 'Compact',
            'CD' => 'Compact',

            'EB' => 'Economy',
            'EC' => 'Economy',
            'ED' => 'Economy',

            '0L' => 'Luxury',

            '1T' => 'Convertible',
            '1V' => 'Van',

            '3H' => 'Hybrid',
            '3I' => 'Hybrid',
            '3C' => 'Electric',
            '3E' => 'Electric',
        ];

        foreach($vehicle_code as $key=>$character) {
            if (array_key_exists($key.$character,$categories))
            {
                $new_car->category[] = $categories[$key.$character];
            }
        }

        if (array_key_exists(substr($new_car->type, 0, 2),$categories))
        {
            $new_car->category[] = $categories[substr($new_car->type, 0, 2)];
        }
```

Comment: Maybe it's just me but I have no clue what you are actually asking.

Comment: I maybe have understood what you are asking. Is this in the right direction? https://3v4l.org/TRYEL

Comment: @Andreas I've updated the question with some more information. Let me know if this makes more sense now.

Comment: You can't even comment on my answer?

Answer (score 0):

Instead of having a list of all of the vehicle codes, have separate lists for the first-character code/category pairs and the last-character code/category pairs. Then, in your loop, you can use `substr($your_vehicle_code, $index_0_or_1, 1)` to get the first or second character and check its existence in the corresponding array. This will allow you to reduce the three entries each of `Compact`, `Economy`, `Premium`, `Mid-Size`, and `Standard` to one each and will also put your functionality more in line with the requirements provided.

For instance, your first character categories array might look something like this:

```
$first_char_categories = [
    'C' => 'Compact',
    'E' => 'Economy',
    'I' => 'Mid-Size',
    'P' => 'Premium',
    'S' => 'Standard'
];
```

You could then check for the code like this:

```
$my_vehicle_code = 'CB';
$first_char = substr($my_vehicle_code, 0, 1); //gives us the character 'C'
if(isset($first_char_categories[$first_char])) {
    $first_char_category = $first_char_categories[$first_char];
    //do something with the first character category
}
```

Comment: I've updated the description. For Compact, Economy, Mid-Size, Premium, and Standard we should be looking at the first two characters. It differs for the others. It's either the second character only or the fourth character only that determines which group the car should fall under. Do you mind taking another look? Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

I have only added the ones you listed in example but as just follow the pattern for the others.
I also changed the "T" and "F" where you had "1T", is the 1 important?

```
$re = '/(EC)\w{2}|(CC)\w{2}|\w(F)\w{2}|(LT)\w{2}|\w(T)\w{2}/';
$str = 'STAR';

preg_match($re, $str, $matches);

// Remove empty values and reset keys
$cat = array_values(array_filter($matches));

    $categories = [
        'CB' => 'Compact',
        'CC' => 'Compact',
        'CD' => 'Compact',

        'EB' => 'Economy',
        'EC' => 'Economy',
        'ED' => 'Economy',

        'IB' => 'Mid-Size',
        'IC' => 'Mid-Size',
        'ID' => 'Mid-Size',

        'PB' => 'Premium',
        'PC' => 'Premium',
        'PD' => 'Premium',

        'SB' => 'Standard',
        'SC' => 'Standard',
        'SD' => 'Standard',

        '0L' => 'Luxury',

        'F' => 'SUV',
        '1G' => 'Crossover',
        '1K' => 'Commercial',
        '1P' => 'Pickup Truck',
        '1Q' => 'Pickup Truck',
        '1R' => 'RV',
        '1S' => 'Sports',
        'T' => 'Convertible',
        '1V' => 'Van',
        '1W' => 'Wagon',

        '3H' => 'Hybrid',
        '3I' => 'Hybrid',
        '3C' => 'Electric',
        '3E' => 'Electric',
    ];

//Echo category 
Echo $categories[$cat[1]];
```

https://3v4l.org/Sg5Xe